# What does the error message "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Could not find any key store entries to support the enabled cipher suites" mean?

Tags: java, android, ssl

I'm currently developing an Android server application. During execution of the code below I get the following error (testing from AVD environment).

> 08-12 21:06:43.098: INFO/System.out(1632): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Could not find any key store entries to support the enabled cipher suites.

```
private void startServer() {
    //Initialize serverSocketFactory
    serverSocketFactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();

    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    try {
        //This is where I got the error...
        serverSocket = serverSocketFactory.createServerSocket(serverPort);
        boolean asdf = false;

        while(asdf) {
            try {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e)                {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (serverSocket != null) {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                //asdfasdfasdf
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error occured during execution of line `serverSocket = serverSocketFactory.createServerSocket(serverPort);`. I couldn't find proper documentation for this error.

Answer (score 3):

It means what it says. The client specified a set of acceptable cipher suites when it said Hello; the server then went to find a certificate that would comply with that set and couldn't. So either the client needs to be less restrictive about cipher suites or the server needs a different kind of certificate. Or possibly the server doesn't have a certificate at all.